# Is the U.S. entity ban against Huawei against the rule of law?

Tags: international, corporate-law, due-process

Is the U.S. entity ban against Huawei against the rule of law? Huawei hasn’t been formally charged or convicted in any court of law and not a single evidence hasn’t been presented to prove Huawei devices being used to spyi or being a threat to U.S. national security, yet Huawei was heavily punished. Doesn't that violate due process laws?

Comment: Which law?  Who's enforcing it?

Comment: You don't think the US has the authority to control which commercial products are allowed to be brought to the US across national borders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are using [rule of law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law) when you mean [due process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_process). The former refers to equality before the law and the subjugation of executive government to the law while the latter refers accepted measures of justice and fairness in the administration of the law and, in the United States, to the supremacy of the judiciary over the legislature (the situation is reversed in the UK).

Assuming that to be the case, the [due process clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_Process_Clause) in the fifth amendment provides that "No person shall ... be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law ...". That is, actions against Huawei must only be taken as permitted by the law.

The law that permits the President to institute the Huawei ban is the [International Emergency Economic Powers Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Emergency_Economic_Powers_Act). As such, at face value, this is a legitimate exercise in executive power. Huawei has the right to challenge the ban in US courts, as such, they have been afforded due process.

Comment: So it wouldn't be against the rule of law to ban any company on a simple whim without the weighing of evidences? And it wouldn't be against due process as long as we allow them to challenge the ban in court?

Comment: @blackbird if the law required discretion and such discretion wasn’t applied then it would be against the law. If the law did not allow appeal on that basis it would be against due process. An action can be unlawful without violating due process.

Comment: So are you saying, because the law just allow the president to do this, it's completely not against the rule of law that the president acts as the judge, jury and executioner in this case?

Comment: @blackbird but the President doesn’t- his decision is subject to judicial review

Comment: Really? Then did he provide the evidence that proved that Huawei was a security threat to the U.S.? Is there any public record of the proceedings?

Comment: @blackbird there's nothing about due process that requires deliberations and discretionary decisions to be published - only that they be made in accordance with the law

Comment: @blackbird if congress passes a law that all left handed males born on a Thursday are to be incarcerated then unless and until the Supreme Court struck it down (which they would) then it is perfectly legal to incarcerate left handed males born on a Thursday. The 'due process' is what give the right to challenge the law.

Comment: Then there's no much distinction between "rule of law" and "rule by law" since "rule of law" doesn't give the guarantee to the people that the ruler won't do things on a whim since the judicial review is done behind closed doors and we can't be sure if it's just for show.

Comment: @blackbird most judicial proceedings are usually public but the important point is the judiciary does not answer to the executive - that is, judges in a "rule of law" country can (and do) rule against the government: that doesn't happen in a "rule by law" jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, but if the judges don't have a say on the most important issues and the process isn't transparent as it should be for the most important issues, the distinction is meaningless, because you would have a "rule-of-law-when-it's-convenient-and-rule-by-law-otherwise" system, because if they're hiding the process then it means they have something to hide.

Comment: @blackbird if this answer has raised other questions please ask them as a question.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of the question is invalid.  Huawei *has* been formally charged in court.

- https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-china-huawei/huawei-pleads-not-guilty-to-u-s-charges-in-new-york-court-idUSKCN1QV2AT
- https://www.cnet.com/news/us-hammers-huawei-with-23-indictments-for-alleged-trade-secret-theft-fraud/

And they've also already lost in court:

- https://www.seattletimes.com/business/technology/july-awards-t-mobile-48m-in-trade-secrets-case-against-huawei/

No evidence?  Here's some:

- https://www.engadget.com/2019/01/30/huawei-t-mobile-emails-espionage-tappy-robot-steal-2012/

and a report on much much more:

- https://fas.org/irp/congress/2012_rpt/huawei.pdf